# How to solve homogeneous linear equations with NumPy?

Tags: math, numpy

If I have homogeneous linear equations like this

```
array([[-0.75,  0.25,  0.25,  0.25],
       [ 1.  , -1.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 1.  ,  0.  , -1.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 1.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , -1.  ]])
```

And I want to get a non-zero solution for it.  How can it be done with [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy)?

**EDIT**

linalg.solve only works on A * x = b where b does not contains only 0.

Comment: [1, 1, 1, 1] is a non-trivial solution.  Anyway, I don't want a particular solution for the example I gave, I want some general way to solve the problem.

Comment: the only [solution](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/RankNullspace.html#rank-and-nullspace-of-a-matrix) that worked for me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use an SVD or a QR decomposition to compute the null space of the linear system, e.g., something like:

```
import numpy

def null(A, eps=1e-15):
    u, s, vh = numpy.linalg.svd(A)
    null_space = numpy.compress(s <= eps, vh, axis=0)
    return null_space.T
```

This yields for your example:

```
>>> A
matrix([[-0.75,  0.25,  0.25,  0.25],
        [ 1.  , -1.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
        [ 1.  ,  0.  , -1.  ,  0.  ],
        [ 1.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , -1.  ]])

>>> null(A).T
array([[-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5]])

>>> (A*null(A)).T
matrix([[ 1.66533454e-16, -1.66533454e-16, -2.22044605e-16, -2.22044605e-16]])
```

See also the section [*Numerical computation of null space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)#Numerical_computation) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Using your code, I get `(A*null(A)).T = array([[-0.375,  0.5  ,  0.5  ,  0.5  ], [ 0.125, -0.5  ,  0.   ,  0.   ], [ 0.125,  0.   , -0.5  ,  0.   ], [ 0.125,  0.   ,  0.   , -0.5  ]])`

Answer (score 8):

For that matter, the best solution of an over constrained homogeneous linear system is the eigenvector associated with the smallest eigenvalue. So given U as the coefficient matrix of the system, the solution is:

```
import numpy as np

def solution(U):
    # find the eigenvalues and eigenvector of U(transpose).U
    e_vals, e_vecs = np.linalg.eig(np.dot(U.T, U))  
    # extract the eigenvector (column) associated with the minimum eigenvalue
    return e_vecs[:, np.argmin(e_vals)]
```

Comment: This is the better solution if your matrix isn't already square (don't need to add any extra columns).

Answer (score 1):

if you are familiar with the SVD decomposition you can use:

_, _, V = np.linalg.svd(A, full_matrices=True)

v=V[-1]

then v is the last row of the last matrix in the decomposition, which correspond to the minimal singular value. thus if you start with a matrix A nxm with n>m then the last singular value must be zero, it means that Av=0