# Getting the non-trivial solution to a set of linear equations

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to write a program that will allow me to solve a system of equations using numpy, however, I want the solution to be non-trivial (not all zeros). Obviously the program is just going to set everything to 0, and boom, problem solved. I attempted to use a while loop (like below), but quickly found out it's going to continue to spit 0 back at me. I don't care if I end up using numpy, I'm open to other solutions if it's more elegant.

I actually haven't solved this particular set by hand, maybe the trivial solution is the only solution. If so, the principle still applies. Numpy seems to always spit 0 back.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

```
x1 = .5
x2 = .3
x3 = .2
x4 = .05

a = np.array([[x1,x2],[x3,x4]])
b = np.array([0,0])

ans = np.linalg.solve(a,b)

while ans[0] == 0 and ans[1] == 0:
    print ("got here")
    ans = np.linalg.solve(a,b)


print(ans)
```

Comment: Is this of any use? [use an SVD or a QR decomposition to compute the null space of the linear system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1836003/9094687)

Comment: Yes, the null space is what Swami seems to be looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the matrix a is invertible. Therefore your system of linear equations has only one solution and the solution is [0, 0]. Are you wondering why you only get that unique solution?

Comment: Na, I hadn't solved that particular set of equations to determine if it has a non-trivial solution. But the same thing is going to continue to happen. If I set both to 0, I'll always end up with the trivial solution.

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. From np.linalg.solve you only get a solution if your matrix a is non-singular. Because in that case, you only have 1 solution. If your b = [0, 0], you will always get [0, 0] as unique solution, no matter what a is (as long a is non-singular). Take for b different values and your solution will be different from [0, 0].

Comment: Alex, I understand that. However, anytime I enter a homogeneous system of equations, i.e. change my x1,x2,x3,and x4 values and make both equations equal 0, I will always end up getting the trivial solution. Because the trivial solution is always going to be the quickest answer to find.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Sympy and it's use of solve and matrix calculations.  Here are the pages for both.

http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/matrices.html

http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/solvers.html